# Starting a new process with arguments

Tags: c#, process

I have a program that receives something like this from a settings file:

```
"C:\Files\App 1\App.exe" "-param1:true -blah"
```

It receives this all as 1 string, but the Process object in C# needs the program and the arguments passed separately. Is there an easy way in C# to parse this, or a way to just pass the statement as it is without parsing it first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var pattern = "\".*?\"";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var cmdString = "\"C:\\Files\\App 1\\App.exe\" \"-param1:true -blah\"";

var matches = regex.Matches(cmdString)
                   .OfType<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Value.Trim('\"'))
                   .ToArray();

var cmd = matches[0];
var arg = matches[1];

var proc = Process.Start(cmd, arg);
if (proc.Start())
    proc.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = @"C:\Files\App 1\App.exe", Arguments = "-param1:true -blah" });
```

If it all comes as one string you can Substring on the index of the first space character.

Comment: other than if a space is in the directory\file name